# retrieving data from single table to compare with another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM `room_type`
WHERE h_id='$h_id'
  AND `rt_oc` >= '$tperson'
  AND `rt_num` <
    (SELECT COUNT(`check_out`)
     FROM `room_info`
     WHERE `h_id`='$h_id'
       AND
       LEFT JOIN `room_type` ON room_type.rt_type=room_info.room_type));
```

Here i want to select data from table1 where it will compare the column value from table2's same column value's sum .

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` should come before your `WHERE`

Comment: Does it help you, m8?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE `h_id`='$h_id'
       AND
       LEFT JOIN
```

This won't work, need to update sub query like this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(`check_out`)
     FROM `room_info`
     LEFT JOIN `room_type` ON room_type.rt_type=room_info.room_type
     WHERE `h_id`='$h_id')
```

By the way, you have `));` in the end of query- check it.

```
SELECT *
FROM `room_type`
WHERE h_id='$h_id'
  AND `rt_oc` >= '$tperson'
  AND `rt_num` <
    (SELECT COUNT(`check_out`)
     FROM `room_info`
     LEFT JOIN `room_type` ON room_type.rt_type=room_info.room_type
     WHERE `h_id`='$h_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `room_type`
WHERE h_id='$h_id'
  AND `rt_oc` >= '$tperson'
  AND `rt_num` <
    (SELECT COUNT(`check_out`)
     FROM `room_info`
        LEFT JOIN `room_type` ON room_type.rt_type=room_info.room_type
           WHERE `h_id`='$h_id'));
```